# @EnvironmentObject bug in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, contextmenu

[image]

When I press the `Move` button in the contextMenu, I change the `isCopied` and `setOriginPath` variables in the EnvironmentObject. When this change is made, the `List` view is cleared and I can't see anything on the screen. I don't have any problems when I don't use EnvironmentObject.

**ContextMenu:**

```
    .contextMenu {
        Button {
            safeFileVM.hideSelectedFile(fileName: currentFile.fileName)
            safeFileVM.takeArrayOfItems()
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(!currentFile.isLock ? "Hide" : "Show")
                Image(systemName: currentFile.isLock ? "eye" : "eye.slash")
            }
        }
        
        Button {
            safeFileClipboard.setOriginPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentFile.localPath)
            safeFileClipboard.isCopied = true
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Move")
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.doc")
            }
        }
    }
```

**View:**

```
struct DetailObjectView: View {

    @ObservedObject var safeFileVM: SafeFileViewModel = SafeFileViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var safeFileClipboard: SafeFileClipBoard
    var currentFile: MyFile
    var currentLocation = ""

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
         .....
        }
        .contextMenu {
            Button {
                safeFileVM.hideSelectedFile(fileName: currentFile.fileName)
                safeFileVM.takeArrayOfItems()
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(!currentFile.isLock ? "Hide" : "Show")
                    Image(systemName: currentFile.isLock ? "eye" : "eye.slash")
                }
            }
            
            Button {
                safeFileClipboard.setOriginPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentFile.localPath)
                safeFileClipboard.isCopied = true
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text("Move")
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.doc")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the mini project below, when the EnvironmentObject value changes, navigation goes to the beginning. Why ? How can I fix this ?

**Example Project:**

**Main:**

```
@main
struct EnvironmentTestApp: App {
    @StateObject var fooConfig: FooConfig = FooConfig()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(fooConfig)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ContentView:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var fooConfig: FooConfig
    private let numbers: [Number] = [.init(item: "1"), .init(item: "2"), .init(item: "3")]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(numbers, id: \.id) { item in
                DetailView(itemNumber: item.item)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Number: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var item: String
}
```

**DetailView:**

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var fooConfig: FooConfig
    var itemNumber: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ContentView().environmentObject(fooConfig)) {
            Text("\(itemNumber) - \(fooConfig.fooBool == true ? "On" : "Off")")
                .environmentObject(fooConfig)
                .contextMenu {
                    Button {
                        fooConfig.fooBool.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        HStack {
                            Text(fooConfig.fooBool != true ? "On" : "Off")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**ObservableObject:**

```
class FooConfig: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fooBool: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: If you're so sure then don't use it, btw needed minimal reproducible example to reproduce and investigate, w/o it it's hard to say samething definite.

Comment: We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, you have to learn the magic of the View struct (body is called when properties change) and @State/@Binding property wrappers (makes the struct behave like an object).

Answer (score 0):

Move that from scene into `ContentView`, because scene is a bad place to update view hierarchy, it is better to do *inside* view hierarchy, so here

```
struct EnvironmentTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
           ContentView()    // only root view here !!
        }
    }
}
```

everything else is inside views, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var foo = FooConfig()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainView()
                .environmentObject(foo)  // << here !!
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var fooConfig: FooConfig
    private let numbers: [Number] = [.init(item: "1"), .init(item: "2"), .init(item: "3")]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(numbers, id: \.id) { item in
                DetailView(itemNumber: item.item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and so on...

Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16

Comment: I will test with Xcode 14 sir.

Comment: There is actually nothing Xcode 14 / SwiftUI 4 specific here, Im just currently on this system.

Comment: same problem. in Xcode 13.4.1

Comment: It's better to make the model store a singleton so it can be used in environmentObject on multiple scenes. And have a different singleton for previews.

Comment: Retested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5 - this solution works fine. Maybe provided code in question should have something else?